# css in javascript calls and returns

Tags: javascript, css

Ok here is my fiddle I will be referring to:
http://jsfiddle.net/9hYv4/11/

In the fiddle everything works perfect, however when I transfer over the code to my wordpress site, things become out of wack.

Firstly:

```
 boxText.style.cssText = "text-decoration: none; border:1px solid #898585;    margin-top: 8px;    background:black;    color:white;    font-family:Verdana;    font-size:10px;    padding: .5em 1em;    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;    -moz-border-radius: 3px;    border-radius: 3x;    text-shadow:0 0px #000000;    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0  8px #000;    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;";
```

Only transfers a few arguments over on my site. namely the color and text decoration. The sizes, fonts, and spacing does not transfer over. Why is this? Is another css on my site conflicting?

and second:

```
boxText.innerHTML = "<a href='" + portfolios[i][4] + "' class='caption-title-link'>" + portfolios[i][0] + "</a><br/><table border=0 style=width:265px><tr>  <td style='padding:8px 0px 4px 0px;' width=127px rowspan=4><a href='" + portfolios[i][4] + "'>" + "<img width=115px src='" + portfolios[i][5] + "'></a></td>  <td width=50px>Type: </td>  <td>" + portfolios[i][6] + "</td></tr><tr><td>Visited:</td><td>" + portfolios[i][7] + "</td></tr><tr><td>Info:</td><td><a href='" + portfolios[i][4] + "' class='caption-title-link2'>My Review</a></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><a href target='_blank'='" + portfolios[i][8] + "' class='caption-title-link2'>Wikipedia</a></td></tr></table>";
```

I made this innerhtml with some classes referring to more css. When I put the css in my styles.css file on my wordpress site none of the parameters transfer over. Can the javascript and the css not communicate like that? how can I fix these two problems!

thanks!!

Comment: Use your browser's debugging tools to inspect the elements on the page and see where the CSS rules are coming from.

Comment: Sounds like your Wordpress CSS is defining rules with `!important`. Not even JavaScript-defined styles can override those...

Comment: so how can I get around this? it's driving me crazy. I have been inspecting for hours now, and I can't figure it out....

Comment: Have you tried defining the CSS as classes and then assign the class instead of text? like `boxText.className = "myclass";` If it does not solve your problem it does at least separate design from content somewhat better.

Comment: @Cory Besides the css is still not being refereed to on the side. If I have class set up in the boxtext.innerHTML, should it be seen by the style.css file?

Comment: @Nilzor not sure if I know how to do that.... new to css and javascript.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/9hYv4/16/

Comment: @Nilzor thanks, but it's still not passing the font size, paddings. Nor is the innerHTML communicating with the css which is located in the style.css file. So what to do??!?